# BibTeX: DLMF web site with organizational author (NIST)

Tags: bibtex

A BibTeX question (using BibDesk). I am having trouble working out how to make BibTeX handle the new Digital Library of Mathematical Functions (DLMF) web page. No authors or editors are listed. DLMF itself suggests (http://dlmf.nist.gov/help/cite)

> When referring to the web site from a print publication,
>   it is recommended to use the following format.
>
> Digital Library of Mathematical Functions. Release date. National Institute of Standards and Technology from http://dlmf.nist.gov/.
>
> where the Release date can be found at the bottom of
>   all DLMF pages.

None of book, webpage, url, ... does it like this. Also, if I put NIST or DLMF in the author field, with or without braces, I get "NIST, " in the refernce list, i.e., it is expecting a first initial.

This is going to be a very highly cited web page. It is the replacement for the venerable Abramowitz & Stegun and will be the standard reference for mathematical functions.

Comment: Which bibliography style (`.bst` file) do you use?